# Does my Multipeer Connectivity App "Use Encryption"? (Submitting to app store)

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, app-store-connect, multipeer-connectivity

I'm currently trying to submit my application to the app store. Its just a chatting app but its Encryption preference is set to required and the text is sent as encoded as seen below.

I have this line of code in my application:

```
   _session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID
                          securityIdentity:nil
                      encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionRequired];
```

and also

```
NSData *dataToSend = [_tvChat.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Itunes Connect Submit for Review Form:

> ```
> Export Compliance
> ```
>
> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or
>   incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only
>   utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)

Does this mean I have to go through the encryption steps to submit my application?
thanks

Comment: UTF-8 encoding certainly doesn't count as encryption.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for your reply. Do you know if this would apply to  the encryption for the connection?

Comment: A chat application that doesn't at least encrypt its communication to the server with SSL/TLS is a menace to its users.

Comment: @CodeInChaos MCSession uses DTLS encryption when encryption preference is `MCEncryptionRequired` (see https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2014/08/20/multipeer-connectivity-follow-up/). But since it's available from iOS API, I cannot answer @manesh answer.